# Open Vine profile from Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, vine

I'm trying to open the Vine (https://vine.co/) Android app to a specific profile page via code.  I've been trying the usual method, via URI with no luck.  Here is my current non-functional code:

```
public void vineButtonClicked(View view)
{
    Intent vineIntent = getVineIntent(view.getContext(), VINE_PROFILE_ID);

    try {
        startActivity(vineIntent);          
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // getVineIntent() doesn't fail on returning a new intent with 
        // the vine:// URI, so this catches the failed intent.  Why 
        // doesn't getVineIntent fail?
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Vine is not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public Intent getVineIntent(Context context, String userProfile) {
    try {
         return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                 Uri.parse("vine://user/".concat(userProfile)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return getWebViewIntent("http://vine.co");
    }
}
```

I tried swapping vine:// for a twitter:// URI scheme and it worked as expected.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Why doesn't getVineIntent fail?

Why would it? All you are doing is constructing an `Intent`.

> How can I make this work?

Get a job at Vine and add support for `vine://` `Uri` values in some app. Apparently, you do not have an app that responds to such a `Uri`, and I am assuming that you already have some Vine client installed on your device.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure why I thought creating an Intent with a broken URI would fail.  So there isn't another way to accomplish this task beyond Vine adding this scheme to their manifest?  It seems odd that they would include this for their iOS version but not Android.

Comment: @karl_: "I'm not sure why I thought creating an Intent with a broken URI would fail" -- any `startActivity()` call, for which there is no matching activity, will fail with an `ActivityNotFoundException`.  "It seems odd that they would include this for their iOS version but not Android" -- not everyone updates their apps in lock-step. Beyond that, you would have to ask Vine.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do the job:

```
String vineUrl = "https://vine.co/u/<PAGE_ID>";
Intent vineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(vineUrl));
vineIntent.setPackage("co.vine.android");

try {
    startActivity(vineIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(vineUrl)));
}
```